# Efficient SQL Using duckdb

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duckdb

Say that I have a system that does not support SQL queries. This system can store tabular or maybe even non-tabular data.

This system has a REST API that allows me to access it's data objects (a table, for example).

Now, my solution for allowing SQL queries to be executed on this data has been to download the contents of the entire data object (table) into a `pandas` DataFrame and then use `duckdb` to execute SQL statements.

The obvious drawback of this method is that I am storing all of this data that I don't even need in a DataFrame before the query is even executed. This can potentially cause memory issues, especially when querying large data objects.

What is a more efficient way to approach this? I am open to approaches using `duckdb` or otherwise.

Comment: more efficient way: keep data in SQL database - even `SQLite`

Comment: I would do that if it were an option, but it is not.

Comment: Depending on your familiarity with suitable languages, you could implement a custom "table function" (similar to the built-in csv table functions) to read the data from your source?

Answer (score 0):

I use `duckdb` in Python to access very big parquet files and it the combination is *blisteringly fast*. They key is that `duckdb` runs the query on the data and only pulls in the data you need. This makes it much faster than reading the whole file into `pandas` and then working with it.

Our company uses an older version of `duckdb` (0.3.4), so check [here](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/data_ingestion) and [here](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview.html) for more recent updates. But this is an example of how I use it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import duckdb as ddb

# File location
my_file = "'/home/my_files/data_stuff.parquet'"  # Note nested single quotation marks.

# Connect
my_db = ddb.connect("test")

# Check connection in a Jupyter code chunk. 
ddb.execute(
   f"""
   SELECT * FROM {my_file}
   LIMIT 10
   """
).df()  # Turns it to a pandas DataFrame.

# Run full query
d = ddb.execute(
   f"""
   SELECT Category1, Category2, SUM(Measure1) as Measure1_sum, AVERAGE(Measure2) as Measure2_avg 
   FROM {my_file}
   GROUP BY Category1, Category2
   """
).df()  # Turns it to a pandas DataFrame.
```